# Simple GPIO design module in SystemVerilog

Tags: io, verilog, system-verilog

I am designing a very crude general-purpose input/output ([GPIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output)) module to provide IO pin control to a RISC-V (like) architecture microprocessor I am currently playing with.

This is the code so far:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module gpio(
    input clk_i,
    input rst_ni,
    input we_i,
    input [7:0] wdata_i,
    input [7:0] addr_i,
    inout [7:0] port_io,
    output [7:0] rdata_o
    );
    
logic [7:0] io_dir;
logic [7:0] io_val;
logic [7:0] io_int;

integer i;

always_ff @(posedge clk_i, negedge rst_ni) begin
    if(rst_ni==0) begin
        for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
            io_dir <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        if(addr_i==0 && we_i==1)
            io_dir <= wdata_i;
    end
end

always_ff @(posedge clk_i, negedge rst_ni) begin
    if(rst_ni==0) begin
        for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
            io_val <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
            if(io_dir[i]==0 && addr_i==1 && we_i==1)
                io_val[i] <= wdata_i[i];
            else
                io_val[i] <= port_io[i];
        end
    end
end

always_comb begin
    for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
        io_int[i] <= (io_dir[i]==0)? io_val[i] : 1'bz;
    end
end

assign port_io = io_int;
assign rdata_o = io_val;
endmodule
```

The code seems to be working as expected. The purpose of this question is to get advice on the quality of my code and what to improve.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, the code has consistent layout, is easy to understand and uses descriptive variable names.

You have a good separation between sequential logic and combinational logic, and you take advantage of the additional automatic code check offered by the SystemVerilog `always_ff` and `always_comb` keywords.  These keywords also convey design intent well.

However, I get compile errors with 2 different simulators due to the `integer i` declaration.  Perhaps your simulator is more forgiving.  Regardless, to make your code more portable, I recommend declaring the iterator variable locally within each `for` loop.

You can easily make the design to be more scalable by using a `parameter` for the number of I/O signals, instead of using hard-coded numbers (7 and 8).  This makes it easier to change the design if you need 16 I/O's, for example.  You could use a parameter named `NUM` and set it to 8:

```
parameter NUM = 8;
```

You can also set the parameter to a different value when you create an instance of the module (without even changing the module itself).  It is customary to use all capital letters when naming a parameter.

You can simplify the `for` loop iterator using the increment operator, `++`.
Change all:

```
i = i + 1
```

to

```
i++
```

When a line has multiple operators, I prefer to use extra parentheses around each term to avoid potential operator precedence issues and to make the code easier to read.  Also, when comparing a 1-bit signal to 1, I prefer to omit the comparison operator.  For example, change:

```
        if(io_dir[i]==0 && addr_i==1 && we_i==1)
```

to:

```
        if ((io_dir[i]==0) && (addr_i==1) && we_i)
```

The `` `timescale `` compiler directive is not needed for RTL code since there are no delays specified.

Some synthesis tools may give you trouble with the `inout` port.  It is quite common to split this single port into separate `input` and `output` ports.

Here is equivalent code with some of the changes outlined above:

```
module gpio #(parameter NUM = 8) (
    input clk_i,
    input rst_ni,
    input we_i,
    input [NUM-1:0] wdata_i,
    input [NUM-1:0] addr_i,
    inout [NUM-1:0] port_io,
    output [NUM-1:0] rdata_o
    );
    
logic [NUM-1:0] io_dir;
logic [NUM-1:0] io_val;
logic [NUM-1:0] io_int;

always_ff @(posedge clk_i, negedge rst_ni) begin
    if (~rst_ni) begin
        for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++)
            io_dir <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        if ((addr_i==0) && we_i)
            io_dir <= wdata_i;
    end
end

always_ff @(posedge clk_i, negedge rst_ni) begin
    if (~rst_ni) begin
        for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++)
            io_val <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) begin
            if ((io_dir[i]==0) && (addr_i==1) && we_i)
                io_val[i] <= wdata_i[i];
            else
                io_val[i] <= port_io[i];
        end
    end
end

always_comb begin
    for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) begin
        io_int[i] <= (io_dir[i]==0) ? io_val[i] : 1'bz;
    end
end

assign port_io = io_int;
assign rdata_o = io_val;
endmodule
```

It is also common to code an active-low reset using the negation operator.

```
if (~rst_ni) begin
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding my two cents to the already great answer by toolic:

1. Using "integer" as a loop iterator is not recommended, as each bit in integer is a 4 state bit (0, 1, x, z).
   Since your loop iterator is basically an internal signal that is only used inside the for loop, this is just a waste of simulator memory.
   This is another benefit of using "int" instead of "integer" --> in "int" each bit is only two states (0, 1).
2. Since you already use system verilog, I will just say that you can simplify the code by replacing:

   ```
   if (~rst_ni) begin
   for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) begin
        somename <= 0;
   end else begin
   ```

   With:

   ```
   if (~rst_ni) begin
      somename <= '0;
   end else begin
   ```

   The syntax '0 means that you wish to set each bit in the target to 1'b0.
   Same logic applies to '1 --> Each bit will be set to 1'b1.

   I like it more than looping over the signal since it's portable to all possible dimensions of the target, and it contains less lines.

3. You are coding a GPIO module with actual tristate values (1'bz), so I would recommend you to support tristate values propagation coding style.
   You can read about it here:
   https://www.verilogpro.com/systemverilog-verilog-x-optimism/

   For your code it means that I would not recommend to use "if-else" statements, but instead use ternary statements in the next sections:

   ```
     end else begin
      io_dir <= (addr_i==0) && we_i ? wdata_i : io_dir;
     end



    end else begin
   for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) begin
       io_val[i] <= (io_dir[i]==0) && (addr_i==1) && we_i ? wdata_i[i] : port_io[i]; 
   end
   ```

   This is debatable topic, and really depends on your methodology and verification tools capabilities. I agree that for your GPIO is not really critical, only something that may expand your knowledge on existing coding styles.